Interchanging structures with different size fields
I have two structures which I use to parse data from an input binary file.
type MyStruct32 struct {
    field1    uint32
    field2    uint32
    field3    uint32
...
}

type MyStruct64 struct {
    field1    uint64
    field2    uint64
    field3    uint64
...
}

I parse data like this:
var o MyStruct32
err := binary.Read(bytes.NewBuffer(data[offset:]), binary.LittleEndian, &o)

The only difference is that the 32 bit version uses 4 bytes per field and the 64 bit version uses 8 bytes per field. The names and order are the same.
I need to be able to validate the incoming data and then use it later in the program. The input data is from a portable executable, so it's necessary to validate that some pointers are within the same program.
I tried to use a simple union of types like so:
package main

import "log/slog"

type MyStruct32 struct {
    field1 uint32
    field2 uint32
}

type MyStruct64 struct {
    field1 uint64
    field2 uint64
}

func CheckDataIsValid[T MyStruct32 | MyStruct64](foo T) (valid bool) {

    if foo.field1 == 0 {
        slog.Info("Not valid, field1 is 0")
        return false
    }

    if foo.field2 > 100 {
        slog.Info("Not valid, field2 is more than 100")
        return false
    }

    return true
}

func main() {
    a := MyStruct32{0, 0}
    b := MyStruct64{100, 1}

    CheckDataIsValid(a)
    CheckDataIsValid(b)
}

This method doesn't allow access to the individual fields, producing the error below:
.\simple_struct.go:17:9: foo.field1 undefined (type T has no field or method field1)
.\simple_struct.go:21:9: foo.field2 undefined (type T has no field or method field2)

Is there a way to make functions that take these interchangeably? I can't find anything obvious except using an interface with lots of getters.

Switching between the types is trivial, with any or a type constraint like MyStruct32 | MyStruct64, but it really depends on how you are using the types. binary.Read is already "generic" and takes any as an argument, so either value can be passed with the same code. You need to show what code you have that isn't already capable of accepting either.

Thanks @JimB, I think the answer I added does what you describe.

note that slog.Info already accepts and empty interface, so your answer doesn’t answer why you think you need this. You could make the same functionality without any of the type parameters. That’s why I was emphasizing that the context matters more than the how for these cases.

I updated the question with an example. The use of slog was for debug output only. If I have missed something even more simple please leave an answer.

With some help from folk on Discord, I discovered how generics can be used to achieve what I am doing in modern versions of Go.
The example program below:

Defines a type MyData, a struct that can have fields which are either uint32 or uint64.
Prints the fields from this structure regardless of the type in the function printGenericStruct(..) to show that individual fields can be accessed like .field1.
Parses two structures directly from an array of []byte to show that generics work with binary.Read(..).

package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "log/slog"
)

type MyData[WordSize uint32 | uint64] struct {
    Field1 WordSize
    Length uint32
    Field2 WordSize
}

func printGenericStruct[WordSize uint32 | uint64](s MyData[WordSize]) {
    slog.Info("Field 1", "field1", s.Field1, "field2", s.Field2, "length", s.Length)
}

func main() {
    a := MyData[uint32]{0, 0, 1}
    b := MyData[uint64]{100, 1, 101}

    printGenericStruct(a)
    printGenericStruct(b)

    data := []byte{1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    offset := 0

    var c MyData[uint32]
    err := binary.Read(bytes.NewBuffer(data[offset:]), binary.LittleEndian, &c)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    printGenericStruct(c)

    var d MyData[uint64]
    err = binary.Read(bytes.NewBuffer(data[offset:]), binary.LittleEndian, &d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    printGenericStruct(d)
}

See also this similar question.
